# Handling 'Overlay Pages' with React Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I am trying to achieve a routing style that enables 'overlay' pages - a modal window that appears on top of the previous page (still visible as the overlay is semi-transparent), but does change the url. A good example of this style is Product Hunt's [homepage](https://www.producthunt.com/).

I previously found a solution by rendering the Route for the overlay outside of a Switch, and then matching the path to the source of the link (it would be linked predictably from two different views only). This worked pretty well.

It looked like this:

```
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/search" component={Search} />
      <Route exact path="/:category" component={Category} />
      <Route exact path="/:category/:id" component={Category} /> // this matches when overlay is active
    </Switch>
    <Route exact path="/:category/:id" component={Overlay} />
```

Now however, the overlays can be displayed from a search page, and clicking on a search result will change the underlying view, where ideally it would stay put in case the user closes the overlay or uses the back button.

This has caused me to rethink my implementation. Instead of directly using `<Link>`s to govern the displaying of the overlay, I am now using React Context to control the overlay, which now makes the url change on mount. At the moment this creates the same behaviour as before, but I'm wondering if there's anything I can do to 'save' the previous url and then use that to control what the `<Switch>` component renders?

If anyone has any input or experience with this kind of behaviour, it's appreciated. I'll make sure to come back with my solution if I find a good one.

Comment: you can make use of a query params instead of a route param to and show the overlay based on that

Comment: That might be a workaround, thanks for your comment! I would ideally like to retain clean urls as the overlay pages will be the most shared.

Answer (score 4):

After having done some research on the react-router docs, I found that it's possible to control the `location` prop of a `Switch` component, which is pretty much exactly what I needed. So I made a wrapper component that used the `withRouter` HOC to analyse the location changes, and if the current location path matched my overlay path, would provide the 'previous' location object to the `Switch`, else it provides the current one. Because the `location` prop doesn't change according to the `Switch`, the underlying view doesn't change or rerender, giving me the exact behaviour I was after.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a code snippet? This is exactly what I need to build but don't quite get what you are saying above. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Building off of @sherlock answer, my solution looks like this in TypeScript.

```
class FeedItemsPage extends React.Component<AllProps> {
  private location: Location

  constructor(props: AllProps) {
    super(props)

    this.location = props.location
    this.overrideLocation()
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps: AllProps) {
    if (this.props.location !== prevProps.location) {
      this.overrideLocation()
    }
  }

  public render() {
    const { match } = this.props

    return (
      <>
        <Switch location={this.location}>
          <Route exact path={match.path + '/'} component={FeedItemsIndexPage} />
        </Switch>
        <Route path={match.path + '/:id'} component={FeedItemPage} />
      </>
    )
  }

  overrideLocation() {
    let location = Object.assign({}, this.props.location)
    location.pathname = this.props.match.path
    this.location = location
  }
}
```